# What's wrong with this php if-statement with 3 conditions?

Tags: php, if-statement

The following if statement has 3 conditions:

```
<?php if ( is_archive() ) : ?>

    <?php $topic_tag_term = get_query_var( 'term' ); ?>

    <?php // Display the top topics of current forum
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'topic',
            'posts_per_page' => '3',
            'topic-tag' => $topic_tag_term,
            'r_sortby' => 'highest_rated',
            'r_orderby' => 'desc',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        );
    ?>

    <?php $term = $wp_query->queried_object; ?>
    <p>The following are a list of topic tagged as <strong><?php echo $term->name ?></strong>.</p>

    <?php if ( bbp_current_user_can_access_create_topic_form() ) : ?>

        <a id="new-entry" href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>/create-topic">Start a new topic</a>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( is_page_template() ) : ?>

    <?php // Display the top topics of current forum
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'topic',
            'posts_per_page' => '3',
            'r_sortby' => 'highest_rated',
            'r_orderby' => 'desc',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'meta_key' => '_bbp_reply_count',
            'meta_value' => '1',
            'meta_compare' => '<'
        );
    ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php // Display the top topics of current forum
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'topic',
            'posts_per_page' => '3',
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'r_sortby' => 'highest_rated',
            'r_orderby' => 'desc',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        );
    ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

For some reason this code is breaking my page.

What is wrong with it?

Comment: don't mix application logic with the display(view). It's *ugly*

Comment: @yi_H View? do you mean stuff like: `The following are a list of topic tagged as`?

Comment: everything that displays something to the client (echo, raw html, etc..)

Comment: @yi_H OK, I will clean up the code.

Comment: Is it just showing a blank white screen or is it cutting off the content after a specific point in the code?

Comment: @Frank Martin the second, but now it is fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php if ( is_page_template() ) : ?>
```

should be

```
<?php elseif ( is_page_template() ) : ?>
```

at least this is the error I can see.

Comment: No it shouldn't theres an `endif` before it

Comment: @locrizak: Which closes the nested `if` as far as I can see.

Comment: Shoot sorry guys I see it now

Answer (score 1):

The colons after your `if (testcase)` should not be there. I think your confusing the use of `?`

Check the manual: [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

No offence but all those `<?php ?>` on every line are just nonsense.

Comment: I'm working on a Wordpress template, and it looks like everything has `<?php ?>` I'm just following the coding style.

Comment: The colons are valid. That is the *alternative syntax for control structures*: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php . Often used for templates.

Comment: @Felix King point taken, thanks for correcting me. @alexchenco gotcha. never worked on Wordpress. just looked like you were overkilling it - guess that's templates for you;)

Answer (score 0):

This line has no semi colon at the end.

```
<strong><?php echo $term->name ?></strong>
```

Comment: You don't need a semi-colon here.